# Finding X & Y positions

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to find the X & Y positions so I can draw my images on a certain part of my game window, but I have no idea how to do this and can't find any information on how to do this, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What X & Y positions are you trying to find? The mouse position? The position of a particular control?

Comment: The mouse position, so I can find where a certain part of the game window is so I can draw the sprite there.

Comment: Your game could be based on a fixed resolution which means this approach is perfectly valid but if it's not then don't forget the x,y values at the right and bottom of the viewport won't always be the values that you're finding with your mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the mouse state from the mouse class found in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

```
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        var x = mouseState.X;
        var y = mouseState.Y;
```